Rename folder file with stat output with bash and/or xargs
I have been trying to solve a little renaming problem.
With bits and pieces taken from this site, man pages etc.
Something fails but I cannot find out what...
I have photo files in a folder, with useless names.
So it would be good to insert the last modification date at the beggining.
A.jpg -> 2024.08.10 A.jpg
For loop in bash
Very ugly but it works !
for i in A*; do echo $i; b="$((stat -c "%y" "$i") | cut -b 1-10 | sed 's/-/\./g') $i"; mv "$i" "$b";done


Shows the file name in the loop
Finds the last modification time, and crops to keep the date only
Replaces the "-" by a point
Concatenates the original filename
Stores all in a variable
Moves the file from original to generated name.

Needed a bit of care on parenthesis etc but it works.
Any advice on "" () $() etc for bash use ?
Just in case it works by luck but not correct.
Find
However I was looking into doing that with find.
find . -name "A*" -exec echo "$((stat -c "%y" {}) | cut -b 1-10 | sed 's/-/\./g') {}"  \;

This does NOT work as stat says  statx '{}': No file with that name
I suspect this is becausein the $(), we are in pure bash.
Replacing with % does not solve the matter.
Should I somehow use an sh -c 'xxxx; yyy' so that I can put several commands, ot is there a way to have find or xargs to allow for it ?
Thaks in advance !
